# How to get records from MySQL into value objects with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, object

I have this code:

```
$Result = DBQuery("SELECT user_id,nick_name,email FROM users LIMIT $fromindex.",".$numOfUsers);
if ($Result)
{
     $resultUsers->UersData=$Result;
}
```

The problem is that the results U get are in some kind of format that i don't know.

I want to get the results in array format, which every element of that array should be a value object class of this type:

```
class UserVO {
    var $_explicitType="UserVO";

    var $id;

    var $nickName;

    var $email;
}
```

Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: So what format do you get them in?

Answer (score 1):

My answer might not sound very helpful, regarding your unclear question. I am supposing, that the function `DBquery` returns the result of `mysql_query(......)`. If thats true, then you are feeding the `userData` with a `Resource string` which is a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) data type.

There are few ways to access such resource String

1. If the query exports multiple results

   ```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData) {
      print_r($row); //This is where you will get your mysql rows.
   }
   ```
2. If the query return single row

   ```
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData);
   print_r($row); // //This is where you will get your mysql rows.
   ```

Here are some must check links

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

Build your DBQuery upon PDO and set the flag PDO::FETCH_CLASS as documented here;

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php